# Algo to find depth and insert sequentially in JSON array

Tags: javascript, json, algorithm, node.js, tree

I have requirement to find relationship from json array based on parentId and insert into array in sequential structure . ParentId maps to _Id which is parent .

```
[{"_Id":1,parentId:"",name:'A'},
{"_Id":4,parentId:2,name:'D'},
{"_Id":2,parentId:1,name:'B'},
{"_Id":5,parentId:3,name:'E'},
{"_Id":3,parentId:1,name:'C'}]
```

The above array need to be converted as below structure with depth field.

```
[{"_Id":1,parentId:"",name:'A', 'depth':1},   
{"_Id":2,parentId:1,name:'B', 'depth':2},
{"_Id":4,parentId:2,name:'D', 'depth':3},
{"_Id":3,parentId:1,name:'C', 'depth':2},
{"_Id":5,parentId:3,name:'E', 'depth':3}]

1
    2
        4
    3   
        5
```

I am a novice programmer and need hint.

```
  var finalArray = [];
 var initPath = function (task) {
     // TODO
 };
 for (var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
     if (array[i].parentId == "") {
         array[i]['depth'] = 1;
         finalArray(array[i]);
         initPath(array[i]);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be the one with parentId 3 be depth = 4?

Comment: @ronnyfm: No, because its parent is at depth 2.

Comment: This sounds doable.  What progress have you made so far?

Comment: var finalArray = [];
var initPath = function(task){
    

};
for(var i = 0 ,len = array.length;i<len;i++){
 if(array[i].parentId== ""){
  array[i]['IndentLevel'] = 1;
  finalArray(array[i]);  
  initPath(array[i]); 
 }
}

Comment: It's probably better to put that much code in an update to the question itself (there should be an "edit" link right below the question.)  It's hard to read in a comment.

Comment: Do you have any guarantees that there are no cycles in the parent-child relationships, such as `{"_ID":42,parentId:42,name:'MeaningOfLife'}` or `{"_Id":7,parentId:9,...}, {"_Id":8,parentId:7,...}, {"_Id":9,parentId:8,...}`?

Comment: Sounds like a great time to learn about recursion.

Comment: @ScottSauyet There is no chance of cyclic relationships.It will be always linear .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I won't do all your work for you, but here is a solution that adds the depths without rearranging the order of the elements.  It's **[on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/NqWRm/1/)**, and here's the relevant code:

```
var addDepth = function(data) {
    var depth = 0, nodes = data.filter(function(item) {
        return item.parentId == "";
    }), total = nodes.length;

    do {
        depth++;
        nodes.forEach(function(node) {node.depth = depth;});
        var ids = nodes.map(function(item) {return item["_Id"];});
        nodes = data.filter(function(item) {
            return ids.indexOf(item.parentId) > -1;
        });
        total += nodes.length
    } while (nodes.length > 0 && total <= data.length);
    return data;
};
```

Note that this changes the array in place, and doens't create a clone.  That might or might not be what you want.  (As I've focused on functional programming recently, it at least slightly offends my own sensibilities.)  This should be relatively easy to change.

Note that this is actually my second version.  The **[first one](http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/NqWRm/)** is to my mind much more elegant.  But it's based on **[the Ramda library](https://github.com/Crosseye/ramda)** I'm still developing.  While I like the library, and find it easy to use, I would not necessarily expect this code to be more obvious to those who don't do a lot of functional programming:

```
var addDepth = function(data) {
    var depth = 0, nodes = filter(pipe(get("parentId"), eq("")), data), 
        total = nodes.length;
    do {
        depth++;
        nodes.forEach(function(node) {node.depth = depth;});
        nodes = filter(pipe(get("parentId"), flip(contains)(pluck("_Id", nodes))), data);
        total += nodes.length
    } while (nodes.length > 0 && total <= data.length);
    return data;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can find the root(s) easy enough: they have no parentId.  Once you have the root(s), you can find all depth 2 nodes: anything whose parent is a root.  Taking this further: a node is at depth n if its parent is at depth n-1 (roots being a special case).  Keep looking until everything has a depth assigned to it.

Comment: Although if the data is bad (cyclic parent structures) you could be looking a very long time!  :)

Comment: How can I make this data more efficient any suggestion ?

Comment: There's nothing particularly wrong with the structure, certainly nothing inefficient.  (The presentation, with it's mixed quoting style, is odd.)  But there is an issue of whether the data is sourced in such a way that you can be certain that there will not be loops such as I described in a comment to the original question.  If there can't be such loops, this approach will work fine.  There might be more efficient ones, but it's a fairly simple approach, and I would try it first.

Comment: Thanks Scott , this structure is old style and available in legacy system. I need to find some solution to build tree structure from this . But yes ,as you said it can be made more  efficient .

Answer (score 1):

The following method will recursively traverse the tree and add 1 to the count each time it goes down another level. It really isn't the most efficient way of doing so, but in my opinion it is the easiest.

```
var array = [{"_Id":1,parentId:"",name:'A'},
{"_Id":4,parentId:2,name:'D'},
{"_Id":2,parentId:1,name:'B'},
{"_Id":5,parentId:3,name:'E'},
{"_Id":3,parentId:1,name:'C'}];

for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
  array[i]["depth"] = findDepth(array[i]);   
}

function findDepth(item) {
    if(item.parentId==="")
        return 1;
    for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
        if(array[i]._Id===item.parentId)
            return 1+findDepth(array[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This could probably be made much more efficient by first making an index object that you could look up the index of an item by its `_Id` property.  Then you wouldn't have to do the inner loop and it would be reasonably efficient.  But it shares the same only-partial-solution characteristic with mine in that it doens't rearrange the elements.

Comment: This also could lead to infinite recursion in a bad data scenario (where the parentId chase each other around a loop.)  The OP says that isn't possible, but I've seen an awful lot of "impossible" data conditions actually occur!  :)